# How do I bind a JQuery UI Datepicker to a text field in a CKEditor dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, ckeditor

I'm trying to bind a JQuery ui Datepicker to a text field in a CKEditor dialog box. The error I'm getting says jQuery(...)datepicker(); is not an object. Which to me says that JQuery ui is not being loaded... ?

The intention is simply to get a datepicker bound to txtDlgReportDate.
I can see that JQuery is being loaded when required but alert(jQuery.ui) returns 'undefined'.

My code is... (Creates a button for a CKEditor toolbar)

Thanks

```
    b='reportSend';
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('reportSend',
    {
        init: function (editor) {
            editor.addCommand('sendReportDialog', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('sendReportDialog'));

    editor.ui.addButton('reportSend',
    {
        label: 'Send Report',
        command: 'sendReportDialog',
        icon: this.path + 'Email16.png'
    });
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add('sendReportDialog', function (editor) {
        return {
            title: 'Send Report',
            minWidth: 400,
            minHeight: 200,
            contents:
            [
                {
                    id: 'general',
                    label: 'Settings',
                    elements:
                    [
                        {
                            type: 'text',
                            id: 'txtDlgReportDate',
                            label: 'Report Date:',
                            labelLayout: 'horizontal',
                            widths: ['100px', '100px'],
                            onShow: function (data) {

                                if (typeof (jQuery) === 'undefined') {
                                    CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', function () {
                                        jQuery.noConflict();
                                    });
                                };

                                if (typeof (jQuery.ui) === 'undefined') {
                                    CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js', function () {
                                        jQuery.noConflict();
                                    });
                                };
                               jQuery(this).datepicker();
                            },
                            commit: function (data) {
                                data.txtDlgReportDate = this.getValue();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'select',
                            id: 'reportType',
                            label: 'Report Type',
                            items:
                                [
                                    ['<All>', '-1'],
                                    ['...Types', '1']
                                ],
                            commit: function (data) {
                                data.reportType = this.getValue();
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            onOk: function () {

                ...send code
                });

            } // End onOk
        }; // end Return
    }); // end dialog Def
} // end init
    });          // End add plugin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And... the issue is that CKEditor doesn't just add an input tag but it surrounds it with a div and a table so the datepicker is added 'inline' to a div... To get it working in a 'click to show' type way we need to get the id of the input tag that's buried in the CK HTML and apply the .datepicker() function to it.

A working version (although it needs a bit more finessing) is....

```
    {
        type: 'text',
        id: 'txtDlgReportDate',
        label: 'Report Date:',
        onShow: function (data) {

            // Set the width of the outer div (otherwise it's affected by the CK CSS classes and is too wide)
            jQuery('#' + this.domId).css('width', 230);
            // Get the input element
            var theInput = jQuery('#' + this.domId).find('input');
            // Apply the datepicker to the input control
            jQuery(theInput.selector).datepicker({
                showButtonPanel: true
            });

        },
```